# Convert Date to String

Tags: formula, date, string

Using a custom formula field, I would like to convert Salesforce standard date (05/03/15) to 05 - March 2015. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Using Date and Date/Time Values in Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US).

In particular, [Converting Between Date and Text](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US#t2d) and [Displaying the Month as a String Instead of a Number](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US#getting-month-as-string).

There are sufficient examples there to format the data as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula that will output a value like:

> 9 - September 2021

It will be blank if the source date field is blank.

```
IF(ISBLANK(DateField__c),
    NULL,
    TEXT(DAY(DateField__c)) & " - " &
    CASE(
        MONTH(DateField__c),
        1, "January",
        2, "February",
        3, "March",
        4, "April",
        5, "May",
        6, "June",
        7, "July",
        8, "August",
        9, "September",
        10, "October",
        11, "November",
        12, "December",
        "None"
    ) & " " & TEXT(YEAR(DateField__c))
)
```

---

Here's another example version for a different format of the date:

> September 9, 2021

```
IF(ISBLANK(DateField__c),
    NULL,
    CASE(
        MONTH(DateField__c),
        1, "January",
        2, "February",
        3, "March",
        4, "April",
        5, "May",
        6, "June",
        7, "July",
        8, "August",
        9, "September",
        10, "October",
        11, "November",
        12, "December",
        "None"
    ) & " " & TEXT(DAY(DateField__c)) & ", " & TEXT(YEAR(DateField__c))
)
```