# Flow to add Date Time to Rich Text Field

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm building a flow to:

Add today's date to a text field. It runs when a record is updated.

I've added a formula resource to the flow

Image below shows the error I'm receiving, please help with constructing the formula.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried converting the date to text using something like "TEXT(TODAY())"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Date to String](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68601/convert-date-to-string)

Comment: This may not behave as expected depending on timezones...

Comment: @PhilW I have tried TEXT(TODAY()) and it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to do any formula variable, you can directly use the **$Flow** resource, like this:

NOTE: It works, the same for normal text/**RichText** fields as well. I have tested it personally.

So here in my example, field => 
The field Api name you want the date to be. (in my case, I just created a text field, named todayDate, so the apiName is todayDate__c). For your's it would be your text field Api Name, that you want the today's date to be in.
[image]

However, if you want it to be something like this,
**31 May 2023 Hello**

Then you can create a new flow resource, 
Resource Type: Text Template 
API Name: **Demo** (you can name it whatever you want)
**Make sure you select Plain Text** 
In the body, you can type in your message, refer to the image below:
[image]

> and then you can assign this text template variable to your field, like this:

[image]

> Here you can see, I set the the field value to **Demo**, because that is the API Name of the Text Template resource I have created.

Hope it helps, if you have any questions, feel free to ask, I am more than happy to help!

Comment: Thanks this is working but displaying the +, for example: 

31 May 2023 +

Test

Comment: You can remove the +, if you don't want to, so, you can just put it as:

{!$Flow.CurrentDate}  Hello

Hope it helps!